# iOS drag and drop with combination

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm trying to figure out if this sort of thing is possible in iOS.

I'd like to have a UI where the user can drag "bubbles", each representing a noun, from a source pool into a destination panel. In addition, I'd like to be able to have another word pool of bubbles, each with adjective bubbles. These adjective bubbles could be dragged over noun bubbles already in the destination panel in order to modify them, making a combined bubble.

Mock-up of what I'm envisioning:
[image: Drag noun bubble to destination]
[image: Drag adjective bubble on top of noun in destination]
[image: Combined desired result]

Is this possible in iOS (any versions)? Preferably using stock controls, but any way is fine. I will admit I have never worked with Objective-C or iOS dev before, but I am aiming for this sort of interface for my app, and want to see if it's at all possible.

Comment: Certainly possible. If you want to use stock controls, you could use simple `UILabel` objects (but if you want the rounded borders around your labels, you'll have to create your own control for that ... maybe create a "blank" PGN image for the background of your label, present that in a `UIImageView` and then present a `UILabel` in front of that). In terms of dragging and dropping, as ColinE said, that's a matter of using something like a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (which is a standard subclass of the `UIGestureRecognizer` class that he referenced).

Comment: By the way, rather than using a "blank" PGN image for the border of your controls you're dragging around, you could do this with Core Graphics, but it strikes me that this would be more complicated for a developer new to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible - but not something you could use 'stock' controls for. I would recommend learning about `UIGestureRecognizer` classes, try this tutorial for starters:

[UIGestureRecognizer Tutorial in iOS 5: Pinches, Pans, and More!](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)